# receiving error 'script.sh: line 150: private: command not found'

Tags: linux, bash, function

I have this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash


BASE_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" > /dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
USER_DEF=$(whoami)

function private {
    read -p "Enter private chat name: " name
    if [[ $name == '' ]] ; then
        :
    else
        if [ -d "$BASE_DIR/chats/private/$name/" ] ; then
            pass=$(cat "$BASE_DIR/chats/private/$name/pass")
            read -s -p "Enter private chat password: " password
            if [[ $password == $pass ]] ; then
                chat "private" "$name"
                count=$(find $BASE_DIR/chats/private/$name/ -type p)
                if [[ "$count" == '' ]] ; then
                    rm -rf "$BASE_DIR/chats/private/$name"
                fi
                echo You exited private chat: $name
            else
                echo Wrong password
            fi
        fi
    fi
    unset $options
    if [[ -e ./chats/public ]] ; then
        options=($(find $BASE_DIR/chats/public -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'))
    fi
    options+=("Enter private room")
    options+=("Create public room")
    options+=("Create private room")
    options+=("Quit")
}

clear
read -r -p "Enter your name [$USER_DEF]: " UD
if [[ $UD = "" ]] ; then
    USERNAME=$USER_DEF
else
    USERNAME=$UD
fi
clear
echo Welcome back $USERNAME
echo We have this chat in public:

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
if [[ -e ./chats/public ]] ; then
    options=($(find $BASE_DIR/chats/public -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'))
fi
options+=("Enter private room")
options+=("Create public room")
options+=("Create private room")
options+=("Quit")
while true 
do
    int_count=1
    for el in "${options[@]}"; do
        echo "$int_count) $el"
        int_count=$(expr $int_count + 1)
    done
    read -p "$PS3" optional
    opt=${options[$(expr $optional - 1)]}
    case $opt in
        "Enter private room")
            private # this is line 150
            ;;
        "Create public room")
            create_public
            ;;
        "Create private room")
            create_private
            ;;
        "Quit")
            echo "Bye, $USERNAME"
            exit 0
            ;;
        [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*) 
            public $opt
            ;;
    esac
done
```

The problem is: **if in menu I press `1`,`Enter` and `1` again i receiving this error:**
`script.sh: line 150: private: command not found`
**this means what? that i'm not able to use it more than 1 time?**

Comment: @Cyrus you know... This is just for show...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
unset $options
```

When `$options` is evaluated it contains, amongst other things, the word `private` so the shell undefines your function.

The correct syntax is

```
unset options
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Didn`t expect that behavior... ***Motivated More for Learning***